# unable to find a lib folder in my project

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been working on some project that involves Jar files to be added to build path. but one of my colleagues said that adding the jars to **lib** folder is advantageous compared to adding it normally.

Now my problem is, in eclipse, I right click and add a java project, but to my surprise I don't find a **lib**, earlier when I used to do J2EE apps, I used to find that. please let me know how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Hm, right-click your project and "New" "Folder" named "lib"? By the way, adding JARs to projects is somewhat 2000's style. Use dependency management e.g. via Maven or Gradle.

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht, thanks for that quick tip. I'll look into it. :)

Comment: right click, build path, add external jar and add the jar file. U'll get the added jar file under 'referenced libraries'. This will add the contentsof the jar file to the project. If you want to add the jar file to the lib folder, copy the jar file and browse through my computer and go into the project where you can find lib folder(sometimes lib folder will not be visible in eclipse). Hope this solved yr prblm.

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse when you create a Java project, it doesn't create the `lib` folder along with it. This is something you want to do manually. At project level you can right click and add the folder. Then you can paste the jars into the folder, select the jars, right click, build path, Add to Build path. 
Alternatively you can directly drag and drop to your `Referenced Library`. Both the ways are similar in effect, no difference.

Comment: I tried this but my Pom.xml still cannot find the Jar.